# Runtime error when trying to use a superclass in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

SOLVED *** Actually the error happened because It wasn't using the methods of the subclass cause they were implemented up in the superclass, that's why it worked if called from a ListaIterador class but don't if called from the upper class.

Hi I created a ListIterator class of a generic type, it extends Iterator so I did implement the iterator's methods in the ListIterator class. The idea is to create an iterator just for using the methods that are available from the Iterator class (read only methods).
First I create a ListIterator, insert some things, and then I want to create an iterator object and use the readonly methods but over the list.
I hope I made myself clear, note that I am coding in spanish, so Iterador means Iterator, Insertar is Insert, also Avanzar means Next.

this code is throwing a runtime execution error and don't know why, maybe you can give me a solution

```
    ListaIterable<int> *iter = new ListaIterable<int>;
    Iterador<int> *ITERADOR = iter;

iter->Insertar(123); //note here I use iter and not ITERATOR for inserting.
iter->Insertar(987); //also here

cout << ITERADOR->ElementoActual()<<endl; //now this method should show the element
ITERADOR->Avanzar() // means next()
cout << ITERADOR->ElementoActual()<<endl;
```

Comment: **What error?** Is it an access violation or segfault from accessing an invalid or null pointer?

Comment: something about assertion fail

Comment: I am trying to do something like this.

Person per = new Athlete();
Person per2 = per;

per2->ShowName(); 

Should work

Comment: Run the code in a debugger and see where the error happens.

Comment: @HoNgOuRu: something about... Include the full description of the error, the place where its raised, and some relevant code about `ListaIterable` and `Iterador`.

Comment: if I create a ListaIterable<int> *list = new ListaIterable<int> then I can insert data in it and recover it.
I only want to recover data from it but from a super class

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error happened because It wasn't using the methods of the subclass cause they were implemented up in the superclass, that's why it wo